# x and y are different sizes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

```py
distrobution.plot(x = ["Observed", "Modelled"], y = ["Amount (mm)"], kind = "scatter")
```

for the following dataframe:

[image: df]

I am getting the error:

```
x and y must be the same size
```

How are they not the same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to plot each series separately:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
df.plot.scatter(x='Observed', y="Amount (mm)", color='blue', ax=ax, legend=True)
df.plot.scatter(x='Modelled', y="Amount (mm)", color='green', ax=ax, legend=True)
ax.set_ylabel('Rainfall (mm)')
ax.set_xlabel('Count')
ax.set_title('Daily Rainfall Distribution')
ax.legend(['Observed', 'Modelled'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `x` and `y` are lists of strings with different lengths. I assume that's what the error message is telling you.